# Android Emulator not working on M1 Chip Mac

Tags: android, macos, emulation

Installed Android Studio.  Created a device.  Did a "Cold Boot Now" and it just sits there and never connects.

I get the message "Connecting to the Emulator" and that's it.

[Connecting to the Emulator Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kAlST.png)

Answer (score 1):

Some people have had issues like this with the embedded, tool window emulator. You can launch the emulator as a separate process by going to Android Studio preferences, Tools -> Emulator and unchecking "Launch in a tool window".

Update: The issue is fixed in emulator 31.2.7 now available in the stable channel.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use images from the **Other images** tab. You can see this tab while creating new AVD after choosing device.